# Run a WordPress website running on Google Cloud Platform as a subdomain of a primary website also running on GCP?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, subdomain, cloudflare

I have two active installations of WordPress on two different instances of the google cloud platform. Now I wanna know if there is a way to make one of them a subdomain of the other.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is to change the configuration of your domains. You don't need to change any files or move your domain files.
GO to the Domain settings, add a subdomain to your desired domain, then point it to the directory of the second website.

It should work, let me know if you got any issues I'm happy to help.